# How to get a faster clock in verilog on a Lattice iCEstick?

Tags: verilog, fpga

The stick has a 12MHz oscillator on board.  http://www.latticesemi.com/icestick

I have managed to write verilog code to divide this clock down and flash LEDs are 1Hz.  (I am just starting to learn verilog.)

I believe that this FPGA will work at up to 133MHz.

Is there a way to generate a faster clock signal (in verilog) from the 12MHz oscillator?

Comment: Is there a DCM on the FPGA?

Comment: I've found that there is a PLL...

Comment: Excelllent.. It should be easy enough to use..

Answer (score 2):

Answer not yet tested.

Via https://www.reddit.com/r/yosys/comments/3yrq6d/are_plls_supported_on_the_icestick_hw/

From: https://github.com/SubProto/icestick-vga-test/blob/master/vga.v

```
wire clk;

  SB_PLL40_CORE #(.FEEDBACK_PATH("SIMPLE"),
                  .PLLOUT_SELECT("GENCLK"),
                  .DIVR(4'b0001),
                  .DIVF(7'b1000010),
                  .DIVQ(3'b100),
                  .FILTER_RANGE(3'b001),
                 ) uut (
                         .REFERENCECLK(pclk),
                         .PLLOUTCORE(clk),
                         .LOCK(D5),
                         .RESETB(1'b1),
                         .BYPASS(1'b0)
);
```

Also:

> iCE40 sysCLOCK PLL
>   The iCE40 Phase Locked Loop (PLL) provides a variety of user-synthesizable clock frequencies, along with cus-
>   tom phase delays.The PLL in the iCE40 device can be configured and utilized with the help of software macros or
>   the PLL Module Generator. The PLL Module Generator utility helps users to quickly configure the desired settings
>   with the help of a GUI and generate Verilog code which configures the PLL macros. Figure 2 shows the iCE40 sys-
>   CLOCK PLL block diagram.

http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/ApplicationNotes/IK/iCE40sysCLOCKPLLDesignandUsageGuide.pdf?document_id=47778

Comment: What does the `FILTER_RANGE` actually do? It does not work correctly in my case if I don't set it, or if I set it to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a higher clock frequency to display a pong game in a VGA monitor using TinyFPGA BX. The TinyFPGA BX and the Lattice iCEstick are quite similar. Therefore, I would like to share my code. You may need to use the official Lattice software for an easier GUI (Graphical User Interface) configuration. https://www.latticesemi.com/software

```
module top(
input wire clk_16,
output USBPU
);

assign USBPU = 0; // drive USB pull-up resistor to '0' to disable USB 
output wire;
SB_PLL40_CORE #(
                .FEEDBACK_PATH("SIMPLE"),
                .DIVR(4'b0000),         // DIVR =  0
                .DIVF(7'b0110001),      // DIVF = 49
                .DIVQ(3'b101),          // DIVQ =  5
                .FILTER_RANGE(3'b001)   // FILTER_RANGE = 1
        ) uut (
                .LOCK(locked),
                .RESETB(1'b1),
                .BYPASS(1'b0),
                .REFERENCECLK(clk_16),  // clk_16_MHz is the original clock
                .PLLOUTCORE(clk)        // clk is the modified clock with higher frequency
                );
```